# How to do URL rewrite in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, lighttpd

I have a rails app that is accessible through multiple URLs, I was wondering what is the best way to rewrite the URL to use the main domain name, abc.com.

I have a bunch of other domain names like
1kjsdf.info
2lksjdfs.info
3sldkjfds.info
... in total 50 of these kinds of domains.

They all end in info if that makes it easier. I used lighttpd as my webserver, is there a way to set things up so that when the user goes to 1kjsdf.info\profile, the url is rewritten as adc.com\profile?

Answer (score 2):

You should probably do this in lighttpd, not Rails.

http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/lighttpd/Docs:ModRewrite

It will be much faster to service these requests in the HTTP server before letting it get to Rails.